# Shortcut's "Start In" analog using registry

Tags: windows, git, registry, shortcut, git-bash

I want to have an ability to run some application (Git bash) on my Windows 10 by passing some command to a Win + R "Run" window.

So I defined a key in my registry:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\gbash.exe,
```

than changed `Default` property to path to the `git-bash.exe` application and specify `Path` property to the `git-bash.exe` parent folder.

Now I have an ability to run GitBash throw Win + R using `gbash` command.

But when I run it using a shortcut, I can specify a `Start In` property, so git will be opened in this specified directory without necessity of doing dozen of `cd`'s,
and when I run GitBash using created `gbash` command, it starts in the default directory.

So how can I change `start in` folder for my `gbash` command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by creating `.bashrc` file in my user directory and adding to this file next row:

```
cd C:/path/to/needed/directory;
```